# How to perform some actions when the state changes, but only for the first update?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a state which initially is `undefined`. After certain actions have been done, I am updating that state and I need to run something as soon as that state is updated. But, since, that state changes quite often, I don't want to use `useEffect` cuz, I don't want the code to be executed everytime state changes. Just for the first update. How can I achieve that? Here is the code demonstartion

```
const [annotations,setAnnotations] =useState()

// A bunch of changes and after some time, called setAnnotations(value)

useEffect(()=> {
// here I need to do something. But, don't have the latest annotations.
// I only need to do // something only for the first time
},[])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want the code to be executed everytime state changes. Just for the first update

You could for example set a custom flag to check whether it already called or not yet. And depend on it.

```
const flag = useRef<boolean>(true);

useEffect(() => {
   if (flag.current) {
     // do stuff
     flag.current = false; // set flag to false so it won't be called anymore
   }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do the same as kind user, but add your state as a dependency  of the useEffect. That way it only runs when the state changes in the first place. Just makes the code a little more robust.

```
const [annotations,setAnnotations] =useState() 

const flag = useRef<boolean>(true);

useEffect(() => {
   if (flag.current) {
     // do stuff
     flag.current = false; // set flag to false so it won't be called anymore
   }
}, [annotations]);
```